# Formatting generated C# code

Tags: c#, formatting, code-generation

### Duplicate

> [C# to format (indent, align) C# properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681500/c-to-format-indent-align-c-properly)

---

I am generating a bunch of code and would like it's initial output (pre ctrl+K, Ctrl+D)  to look reasonable. Managing indents is a royal pain and there has to be a utility or class out there I can embed inside of my code generator. I am embedding this into a VS add-in and in a build process so I am not interested in an external program. I need something I can call programatically.

Recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [IndentedTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.indentedtextwriter.aspx) that is provided with the Microsoft .NET Framework to help with indenting code. There is sample usage included with the class documentation.

Comment: That's not going to be terribly useful without writing a parser to understand C# syntax and therefore decide when to indent/unindent.

Comment: Right, I misunderstood the question.