# Format C# code with indents programmatically

Tags: c#, formatting

I'm making a C# application including a `RichTextBox` in which the user will be able to put some C# code in it and format it by indents like what Visual Studio does.

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //rchCode.Text= formattedCode; // Which I haven't got anywhere so far
}
```

I looked for the same questions and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/681812/2263683) suggests using something called [NArrange](http://www.narrange.net/), but I don't want use other tools, add-ins or such.

Also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/681648/2263683) offering the CodeDOM way which I haven't figure it out how to use it (*If it's helpful in anyway*)

I want to do it by writing some actual code. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got the solution this way:

It's not still perfect (*as it always add one or more new lines before the first code line*). So if anyone can improve it or has a better way to do it, I'll appreciate any new suggestions.

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox rchTemp = new RichTextBox();
    foreach (string line in rchCode.Lines)
    {
        rchTemp.AppendText("\r\n" + line.Trim());
    }

    RichTextBox rchTemp2 = new RichTextBox();
    int indentCount = 0;
    bool shouldIndent = false;

    foreach (string line in rchTemp.Lines)
    {
        if (shouldIndent)
            indentCount++;

        if (line.Contains("}"))
            indentCount--;

        if (indentCount == 0)
        {
            rchTemp2.AppendText("\r\n" + line);
            shouldIndent = line.Contains("{");

            continue;
        }

        string blankSpace = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < indentCount; i++)
        {
            blankSpace += "    ";
        }

        rchTemp2.AppendText("\r\n" + blankSpace + line);
        shouldIndent = line.Contains("{");
    }
    rchCode.Text = rchTemp2.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

To properly indent code you would need Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp nuget package and .NET framework 4.6+. Sample code:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

...

public string ArrangeUsingRoslyn(string csCode) {
    var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(csCode);
    var root = tree.GetRoot().NormalizeWhitespace();
    var ret = root.ToFullString();
    return ret;
}
```

One-liner:

```
csCode = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(csCode).GetRoot().NormalizeWhitespace().ToFullString();
```

You may also use [NArrange](http://www.narrange.net/) to sort methods in your cs file, organize usings, create regions, etc.

Comment: used to below code, it works fine in C# file but not working in cshtml file.Is any other solution for html file

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string FormatCode(string code)
    {
        var lines = code.Split('\n').Select(s => s.Trim());

        var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        int indentCount = 0;
        bool shouldIndent = false;

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (shouldIndent)
                indentCount++;

            if (line.Trim() == "}")
                indentCount--;

            if (indentCount == 0)
            {
                strBuilder.AppendLine(line);
                shouldIndent = line.Contains("{");

                continue;
            }

            string blankSpace = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < indentCount; i++)
            {
                blankSpace += "    ";
            }

            if (line.Contains("}") && line.Trim() != "}")
                indentCount--;

            strBuilder.AppendLine(blankSpace + line);
            shouldIndent = line.Contains("{");
        }

        return strBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Little improvement on answer on top

if line public string Foo { get; set; } correct indent.